What does "1o (degree symbol) tempo" mean
What does "1o tempo" mean?

Seriously, a duplicate of a duplicate? Not a duplicate of the question that the previous duplicate was a duplicate of? Shouldn't duplicate-ness be transitive? This smells of either the first or the second being similar, but not really a duplicate.

The degree symbol is actually just a superscript "o" used to signify an ordinal number.

To give a little detail, it isn't a degree sign, it's the ending -o formatted as superscript. The whole phrase is "primo tempo" (can also be "tempo primo"), which is Italian for "first tempo".

@phoog While I was typing... okay, I'm leaving it here anyway.

@Divizna I really like the transitiveness argument, but I observe that equivalent questions may be posed in forms of very different similarity to a given question. I consider it more helpful, to link to the most similar question instead of the oldest one, or the one at the end of a duplicate link chain. (This may deserve a discussion in META, but probably already exists there). Also this duplicate research takes time and top priority is to avoid giving another answer instead of observing duplicity (preventing others to add further answers, i.e. waste time with a duplicate).

@Divizna: Here is a corresponding meta discussion.
